# Issue relatedto list.append method

Tags: python, regex, list, append

I was checking the regular expressions and i created a program which was reading text from a text file and it was extracting the emails but i have a problem when i try to append the result to the list and try to print the data inside of the list nothing happens but while appending the data to the list i tried to print the data and it was printing the data but outside of while loop list is empty. i am actually very new to python so i am not sure it is happening. thanks.

```
import re
my_list = []
my_file = open("D:\\rand.txt",'r')

while my_file:
   line = my_file.readline()
   result = re.search(r"\w+@\w+.com",line)
   if(result):
      my_list.append(result.group())

for list_items in my_list:
    print(list_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop will never stop since you're testing the condition against `my_file` and it should be tested against the `readline` result. You could keep the `my_file` at the while loop, but you would have to add a condition to break the loop based on the response of (again) `readline` (`if line == "": break`). It would be also interesting to escape the dot in your regex since it looks like you are trying to capture a literal `.com` ending (and not any character follow by a literal `com`), let me know if you think otherwise.

Input **rand.txt**

```
Morbi porttitor lorem id ligula. Suspendisse ornare bballc@oakley.com consequat lectus.
In est risus, dferreiro1@yelp.com auctor sed, tristique in, tempus  sit amet, sem.
Aenean congue, diam id ornare imperdiet, asantello4@geocities.jp nisi vulputate nonummy.
Fusce  consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl. Duis cakram2@live.com bibendum, felis sed.
```

```
import re
my_list = []
my_file = open("rand.txt",'r')

line = my_file.readline()
while line:
   result = re.search(r"\w+@\w+\.com",line)
   if (result):
       my_list.append(result.group())
   line = my_file.readline()

for list_items in my_list:
    print(list_items)
```

Output from *list_items*

```
bballc@oakley.com
dferreiro1@yelp.com
cakram2@live.com
```